# How is a semaphore actually implemented (possibly without queue)?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, semaphore

I am implementing a semaphore in the kernel, I am given two kernel tools used to block/unblock processes. `Block(pid)` and `Unblock(pid)` respectively.

EDIT: Block() takes the pid of a process and provent the kernel from scheduling the process further until an Unblock() instruction is called with the that pid.

and I have to implement two kernel methods which controls the semaphore

```
/*
*pid:calling process id, there is an array keeps tract of all pid
*sem: shared semaphore id, there is an array keeps tract of all sem
*/
void Take(pid,sem){} 
void Give(pid,sem){}
```

I haven't wrapped my head around of how to keep track of the blocking and unblocking mechanism. 
For example I have two processes

```
#define Semaphore sem1;
Process A{
  kernel_take(sem1);
  //..do something
  kernel_give(sem1);
}
Process B{
  kernel_take(sem1);
  //..do something else
  kernel_give(sem1);
}
```

Now Process B's `take()` is likely called before Process A calls `give()`, and B becomes blocked by B's `take()`. How does A unblock B in process A's `give()`? Or should A's `give()` signal B's `take()` to unblock B? 
Also could it be done without a queue? Since we can't use any external libraries in the kernel, creating my own queue could bloat up the kernel

Comment: Many processors include "compare and swap" instructions which provide the primitive support for other synchronization operations.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately we can't assume hardware support since this is an assignment on an abstract kernel

Comment: Then you can assume an abstract CAS instruction.

Comment: Well, you need a definition for "Block" and "Unblock" then.

Comment: @HansPassant The program has to be able to run on both my computer and professor's and my grader's computer.. don't think CAS is an option in general.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't have the definition for Block and Unblock, they are precompiled. All I know is that Block() takes the pid and kernel stops scheduling that process until Unblock() of the same pid is called.

Comment: You will have hard time without a queue. However you can use standard kernel semaphore (mutex). It will maintain queue for your.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk this is a custom kernel, the point is to implement a kernel semaphore... So I basically need to have a queue for each semaphore, that could take up a lot of space.

Comment: @Yonk yes, you will need a queue for each instance of semaphore. Unless your kernel has other means how to wake up suspended thread.

Comment: Process/thread control blocks are often on some queue or other - mutex, semaphore, timeout, ready queues of different priorities, in an exclusive manner.  It's common for the control blocks to have a link pointer, (or pointer-pair for double-link), to faciltate queueing them together without explicit queue space.